# open url is Timeout::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, url

```
  uniqUsers = User.find(params[:userid]).events.where("comingfrom != ''").uniq_by {|obj| obj.comingfrom}

  uniqUsers.map do |elem|
     begin
       @tag = nil
       open('http://localhost:3000/search_dbs/show?userid='+ params[:userid] + '&fromnumber=' + elem.comingfrom + '&format=json', 'r', :read_timeout=>1) do |http|
         @tag = http.read
       end
     rescue  Exception => e
      puts "failes"
      puts e
     end
 end
```

hi , this is driving me crazy , for some reason the open url command is running out of time with no error. when i try the same url in chrome everything works like a charm, when im doing this from the code i get Timeout::Error

Comment: Are you running this on the same machine as Chrome? Do you have an application-level firewall that prevents Ruby from making connections?

Comment: Have you tried increasing `read_timeout`? You have it set at just one second (`:read_timeout=>1`), which might not be enough. Try setting it to something much higher.

Comment: One second is extremely low. Some sites can't get their act together in five seconds.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code so its readable, and remove all unnecessary code. Reduce it to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: i tried 30 seconds , still the same issue. there is no firewall,

Answer (score 0):

One second is optimistic.

When I was writing spiders, I'd create a retry queue, that contained sub-arrays or objects that contain the number of retries previously attempted, the URL, and maybe the last timeout value. Using an incrementing timeout value, the first time I'd try one second, the second try two seconds, four, eight, sixteen, etc. until I determined the site wasn't going to respond.